# How do I determine the optimal number of threads in Spark application?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, multiprocessing

In my **Scala/Spark** application, I am trying correctly to use multiprocessing. As you can see from the code below, the number of threads is equal to the number of elements in the `storage` array. I tested the current code and it works. But as you can see there are only 2 elements in the `storage` array. It seems to me that if there are a large number of elements in the array, problems will occur. In my case, I don't know how many elements there will be in the array in the future. Perhaps I should limit the number of threads and start new threads only when the previous ones are processed.

**Question:** How do I determine the optimal number of threads?

**Main.app:**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import utils.CustomThread

object MainApp {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      // Create the main DataFrame with all information.
      var baseDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("/path_to_the_files/")

      // Cache the main DataFrame.
      baseDF.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

      // The first time DataFrame is computed in an action, it will be kept in memory on the nodes.
      baseDF.count()

      // Create arrays with the different identifiers
      var array1 = Array("6fefc487-bd57-4fa2-808a-3845703b83d0", "9baba76b-07c2-48ec-a153-6cfb8b138ecf")
      var array2 = Array("ab654369-77f5-478c-94e5-ee2755ae8571", "3b43e0a6-deba-4919-a2cc-9d450e28e0fe")
      var storage = Array(array1, array2)

      // Check if the main DataFrame is empty or not.
      if (baseDF.head(1).nonEmpty) {
        for (item <- storage) {
          val thread = new Thread(new CustomThread(baseDF, item))
          thread.start()
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**CustomThread.scala:**

```
package utils

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

class CustomThread(baseDF: DataFrame, item: Array[String]) extends Runnable {
  override def run(): Unit = {
    val df = baseDF.filter(col("col1").isin(item:_*))

    println("Count: " + df.count())
  }
}
```

I use such configurations:

```
spark.serializer: org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max.mb: 1024
spark.executor.memory: 2g
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold: -1
spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles: true
spark.driver.memory: 30g
spark.driver.maxResultSize: 20g
spark.executor.cores: 1
spark.cores.max: 48
spark.scheduler.mode: FAIR
```

Comment: Benchmarks (p.s. `var` and `Array` are to be discouraged)

Comment: Use `Future`. Or–perhaps less recommended–parallel collections. They will deal with all the threading nonsense for you.

Comment: The number of threads that your executor uses depend of the number of cores and the partitions of your dataset. Your code will create a runnable in your driver app. Unless you want to do multi-threaded tasks, and this can be achieved with the RDD mapPartitions function, with the spark SQL it is not possible.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 But the above code will run parallel jobs. For the executors, there is no difference

Comment: Guys, in fact, my post has a very simplified code. Instead of counting the number of elements, in reality, I do other time-consuming actions. I have a main large DataFrame (`baseDF`). In the loop, I filter that main DataFrame with different parameters from the array (`storage`) and create an Excel file from filtered DataFrame (`df`), transfer it to a remote SFTP server, log all actions, e.t.c. Creating only one Excel file can take 1~2 hours, depending on the DataFrame size. Now think about how long it might take if you need to create 100 files in sequence. What do you think now?

Comment: @Jasper-M сould you please provide examples of how you would use `Future` in my task?

Comment: @cchantep Benchmarks it's exactly what I am doing right now. I use `Mesos` for that. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 as far as I understand there is multiprocessing at the Scala level and multiprocessing at the Spark level. What you described in your previous comment concerns Spark. I'm interested in multithreading at the Scala level.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek Ok if you are interested in multiprocessing at the Scala-Level, then you should remove the spark-tag, its just confusing. If writing 1 Excell file takes 1-2h, then maybe this should be investigated first? I assume this writing runs on executors?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I have already studied this part. In `Mesos` I see that filtered DataFrame is 8TB. I use [spark-excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel) package to create an Excel file from the existing DataFrame. Since the DataFrame is large, writing to an Excel file takes 1~2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve with your multi-threading? In a spark application, you should not worry about the number of threads etc. What your code does is the launch parallel jobs (your multi-threading is only on the driver), for the executors, there is no difference.

In my experience, I only use parallel job launches if I have several jobs which are small or skewed, such as the cluster resources are not fully utilized. If I do that, I use scalas parallel collections.

To answer your question : The optimal number if threads is probably 1

EDIT: I would suggest to rewrite your code completely with the goal to have all results in a new dataframe, this is better than implementing complicated multi-threading:

```
// testcase
val baseDf = Seq(
  "6fefc487-bd57-4fa2-808a-3845703b83d0",
  "9baba76b-07c2-48ec-a153-6cfb8b138ecf",
  "ab654369-77f5-478c-94e5-ee2755ae8571",
  "dummy"
).toDF("col1")

var array1 = Seq("6fefc487-bd57-4fa2-808a-3845703b83d0", "9baba76b-07c2-48ec-a153-6cfb8b138ecf")
var array2 = Seq("ab654369-77f5-478c-94e5-ee2755ae8571", "3b43e0a6-deba-4919-a2cc-9d450e28e0fe")
var storage = Seq(array1, array2)

broadcast(storage.toDF("storage"))
  .join(baseDf,array_contains($"storage",$"col1"),"left")
  .groupBy($"storage").agg(count($"col1").as("count"))
  .show()
```

gives :

```
+--------------------+-----+
|             storage|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|[ab654369-77f5-47...|    1|
|[6fefc487-bd57-4f...|    2|
+--------------------+-----+
```

Comment: In fact, my post has a very simplified code. Instead of counting the number of elements, in reality, I do other time-consuming actions. I have a main large DataFrame (called `baseDF`). In the loop, I filter that main  DataFrame with different parameters from the array (called `storage`) and create Excel file from filtered DataFrame (called `df`), transfer it to a remote SFTP server, log all actions, e.t.c. Creating only one Excel file can take 1~2 hours, depending on the DataFrame size. Now think about how long it might take if you need to create 100 files in sequence. What do you think now?